# How to shorten the length of the path on the one folder in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, path, split

How to shorten the length of the path on the one folder in Matlab?

i.e. I want one directory up.

For example I have 'C:/mydir/folder1/folder2' I want 'C:/mydir/folder1'

Comment: what's wrong with appending it with `'..'`? `fullfile( currFolder, '..' )`?

Comment: @Shai did you try it? it doesn't work at least in R2012a, just adds '..' to the end of path

Comment: indeed. but it points to the parent directory, isn't it what you want? `'c:/parent/curr/..'` points to the same folder as `'c:/parent'`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the folder path in a string, you can use the function [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html):

```
currentFolder = pwd;
parentFolder = fileparts(currentFolder);
```

Note that this won't work if the folder path string ends in a file separator character (i.e. `'/'` or `'\'`).

If you simply want to change to the parent directory of the current working directory, use [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html):

```
cd ..
% or
cd('..')
```

Comment: @mrgloom: If there's no file specified, and the last character isn't a file separator, it will lop off the trailing folder.

Answer (score 2):

We could also use [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29) builtin functions:

```
char(java.io.File(pwd).getParent())
```

also the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getFullPath%28java.lang.String%29) library that ships with MATLAB:

```
char(org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getFullPath(pwd))
```

Comment: When people ask me why I find Matlab to be an overpriced heap of crap, I'll direct them to this question.  @Amro, thanks for your answer nonetheless! :)